# Como verificar se os campos senha são iguais e maiores de oito dígitos?

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho o seguinte **HTML** e gostaria que houvesse uma verificação em `javascript` para ver se nos campos os caracteres digitados são iguais e maiores de oito dígitos, para assim habilitar o botão `submit`.

Tenho um código `JavaScript` que verifica o número de caracteres, mas preciso que também verifique se são iguais os campos e habilite o botão caso tudo seja positivo.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ 

document.querySelector("[name='senha_imob']").oninput = function(){
   this.style.backgroundColor = this.value.length >= 8 ? "red" : "#D9ECF1";
}    
         });
    </script>

<input name="senha_imob" type="password" class="imv-frm-campo">

<input name="rsenha_imob" type="password" class="imv-frm-campo">

<input type="submit" name="btn-entrar" value="ATUALIZAR" class="frm-botao" />
```

Comment: Gladison, sua pergunta está sendo sendo negativada porque você não apresentou nenhuma pesquisa ou código que tenha tentado; apenas postou um código HTML, e pediu que fosse feito o resto. Sugiro dar uma lida em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso pode te ajudar:

```html
<input name="senha_imob" type="password" class="imv-frm-campo">

<input name="rsenha_imob" type="password" class="imv-frm-campo">

<input type="submit" name="btn-entrar" value="ATUALIZAR" class="frm-botao" disabled />

<script type="text/javascript">
 let campoSenha = document.querySelector('input[name="senha_imob"]');
 let campoConfirmarSenha = document.querySelector('input[name="rsenha_imob"]');
 let botao = document.querySelector('.frm-botao');

 campoSenha.addEventListener('input', function(){
  verificaCampos();
 });

 campoConfirmarSenha.addEventListener('input', function(){
  verificaCampos();
 });

 function verificaCampos() {
  if(campoSenha.value == campoConfirmarSenha.value && campoSenha.value.length > 8)
   botao.disabled = false;
  else
   botao.disabled = true;
 }

</script>
```

Comment: tente digitar o seguinte valor no input: 1111111
veja se a validacao passa...
eu transformaria o valor do input em String por seguranca
if(campoSenha.value == campoConfirmarSenha.value && String( campoSenha.value ).length > 8)

Comment: Realmente não passa porque o campo input precisa ter mais que 8 caracteres, se você incluir apenas 7 não passará na validação mesmo. Não é necessário converter para string já que ele já é uma.